# Zero-copy in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, zero-copy

I have large file (usually 300 MB to 2 GB) which consists of smaller files. I want to *unpack* them to folder and I want to do that efficiently ([zero-copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy)).

I found, that .NET Framework have [TransmitFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.transmitfile?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_HttpResponse_TransmitFile_System_String_System_Int64_System_Int64_) method for that

```
using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(outputPath))
{
    HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse(writer);

    response.TransmitFile(inputPath, offset, length);
}
```

but what about .NET Core, that I'm targeting...?

[IHttpSendFileFeature Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features.ihttpsendfilefeature?view=aspnetcore-2.2) looks promising and it is probably implemented in [OwinFeatureCollection class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.owin.owinfeaturecollection.microsoft-aspnetcore-http-features-ihttpsendfilefeature-sendfileasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2), but how can I use it?

Comment: How would sending a file 'unpack' it?

Comment: Is P/Invoking an option(Windows only solution?) or you want your solution to be cross platform dependent?

Comment: @Neil, OP wants to read and transmit it without creating copy of the data

Comment: Why would transmitting a file make a copy of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently sending files from asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979668/efficiently-sending-files-from-asp-net-core)

Comment: @Neil, I do not have in depth detail but if you search for Zero-Copy then you will see that usual way the sending file is implemented such that "it will buffer the file in memory". OP does not want to. WinAPI offers a method "TransferFile" for that

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü This sounds to me like 'premature optimization'.  Unless it is running in exceptionally small amounts of ram (like a few 100 MB), then this really is not an issue.  There are many different parts of Windows that will 'buffer' data, that you really can't control from a C#.  Don't worry about it until you have a working system, that you can measure the 'issues', and THEN if it's a problem, work around it.

Comment: @Neil I want to copy part of the large file to the new one, without copying data to user-space. Look at that zero-copy reference ;-).

Comment: @Neil, Yeah you are right. It may very well be early optimization. However, on wikipedia page it mentions that `Zero-copy protocols are especially important for high-speed networks in which the capacity of a network link approaches or exceeds the CPU's processing capacity.`

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü If P/Invoking will be necessary, I will probably stay with [Stream.CopyToAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copytoasync)...

Comment: You can easily use `TransmitFile` from here ;) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/desktop/api/mswsock/nf-mswsock-transmitfile

Comment: To answer your inquiry about the `IHttpSendFileFeature`, something like this should work, though note it falls back to slower variations if the feature is unsupporter. `var sendFileFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpSendFileFeature>(); await sendFileFeature.SendFileAsync("filename", offset, byteCount, cancellationToken);`

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thanks, this could work! Just to figure out, how to use it properly ([first attempt](https://i.imgur.com/OiMd5Gg.png)).

Comment: Yah that's because the feature is null. I misunderstood and thought you were working inside of an asp application. You're not going to use the feature (at least this way)

Comment: Ah, okay. So it seems impossible to do zero-copy in .NET Core without running server like Kestrel...

Comment: I dug through the asp source... Seems like https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/85e2147ff037cc9950249fbb9d095ad47ec4184a/src/Servers/HttpSys/src/RequestProcessing/ResponseBody.cs does part of the work (look for SendFileAsync) but it ultimately calls out to https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/85e2147ff037cc9950249fbb9d095ad47ec4184a/src/Servers/HttpSys/src/RequestProcessing/ResponseBody.cs and uses `IOCompletionPorts` and `Overlapped` perhaps you can review and get some ideas. Overlapped io seems promising.

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü If you are worried about >high-speed networks, then you don't write your code in C# :-)

Comment: @Neil, I do not believd this is not a good argument. .Net or Java for that matter is not as fast as other other native languages such as c or c++ is quite old

Comment: In general you might be correct but if you are worried about memory use and high speed network transfers then you don't use c# or java. See the many jobs for c++ on for the stock markets where microseconds mean money.